# SQLite - how to write a correct join?

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables. First one:

```
create table history ( id integer primary key, task integer )
```

And second one:

```
create table task ( id integer primary key, name text )
```

What will be an SQLite query that will return a list of history.id and task.name where history.task == task.id ( all items from 'history' table with 'name's from 'task' table )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT history.id, task.name
    FROM history
    INNER JOIN task
    WHERE history.task = task.id
```

Use a LEFT JOIN if you aren't sure that the task will be present for a particular row in history - nulls will be returned if the row is missing.

The syntax for SELECT is described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-core) (using pictures).

Comment: What's the difference between inner join and left join in my case?

Comment: If you only want rows returned that have both a history and a task then you should use INNER JOIN. If you don't mind getting back rows that have a history but no task, then use a LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT history.id, task.name FROM history LEFT JOIN task ON history.task = task.id
```

Comment: What's the difference between inner join and left join in my case?

Comment: A left join will show all history ids regardless of whether the row has a matching task. An inner join will only show where both are present.